# Error message '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lIL'; how do I install that library?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I am installing OpenFEC (www.openfec.org) on Ubuntu by first running `cmake ..` from inside the directory *build*; and then running the command `sudo make`.
It goes fine until the following occurs:

```
Linking C shared library ../../bin/Release/libopenfec.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lIL
```

What library is that and how do I install it?

**Answer to the question:**
I found it here: [Link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?arch=i386&searchon=contents&keywords=libIL.so.1).

On Ubuntu it is installed by running the command: 
`sudo apt-get install libdevil1c2 libdevil-dev`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu it is installed by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libdevil1c2 libdevil-dev
```